# Поиск корней полинома

Tags: c++, boost, численные-методы

Как найти корни полинома, заданного через `boost::math::tools::polynomial<double>` на промежутке [0,1] используя тот же `boost`? Чтение документации не особо помогло в решении.

Answer (score 1):

Эта часть буста нужна лишь для арифметических операций. Вам нужны численные решения. Более того, все корни, вероятно, не найти. Как правило, алгоритмы сходятся к одному. Я не большой спец. в числаках. Но универсального алгоритма, без костылей, котрый искал бы корни, я не знаю.

Вы можете посмотреть следующую [ссылку](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_64_0/libs/math/doc/html/rooting.html).

Вероятно, вам нужно обратиться к

- Root Finding With Derivatives: Newton-Raphson, Halley & Schröder
- Examples of Root-Finding (with and without derivatives)

Хочу заметить, что здесь же представлены безградиентные методы (т.е. методы для функций, которые не задаются в аналитическом виде):

- Root Finding Without Derivatives

Comment: Не знаю на счет "без костылей", но есть [Jenkins-Traub algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jenkins%E2%80%93Traub_algorithm). При желании можно собрать и приспособить оригинальный код на фортране.